# How do I split a string of numbers separated by commas into a list?

Tags: python, split

I am trying to split a string of numbers separated by commas into a list but it it giving me this error:

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

This is what I've tried:

```
numbers = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 500, 600, 800"

numbers_list = numbers.split(",", " ")

print(numbers_list)
```

Comment: The correct command here is `numbers_list = numbers.split(", ")`. `split()` only takes one string argument.

Answer (score 1):

The `.split` method only takes one string argument, the second argument is an integer and specifies the maximum number of splits. So, if the second argument was 2, it would only split the string up to 2 times, which would get you a list with a length of 3. But since you don't care about exactly how many times the string gets split, you can ignore the second argument. You would probably also want to get rid of the space in between the numbers, so you would also include that along with the comma. With all this taken into account, you final code would look like this:
`numbers_list = numbers.split(", ")`

Answer (score -1):

```
import re
 
numbers = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 500, 600, 800"
 
val = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', numbers)
li = val.split(" ") 
li2 = [] 
for i in li:
 if i == "":
     pass
 else:
     li2.append(i)
 
print(li2)
```

import regex, And try this code

Comment: Actually, it won't work.  Did you try it?  Your code will keep all the spaces.

Comment: That made it much worse.  This is not a regex problem.  The previous answer was right, just do "val.split(", ")`, where the inside string is "comma space".  That's all he needs.

Comment: I did some changes in above code now try this. @TimRoberts